# postgres database stores timetz without gmt offset in live server

Tags: postgresql

I have used Postgres 12.3 in local development server(windows platform) and Postgres 9.2.24 in live server(Linux platform). here i am notice one problem in timestamp with time zone datatype. because, in local server select query returns data as TIME+5:30 (UTC + 5:30) but in live server return only TIME without GMT Offset (same query). so how to solve or handle this problem? please help me solve this issue.

```
SQL: select start_time from course_batches;
```

Postgres 12.3:

> > 18:00:00+05:30

Postgres 9.2.24:

> > 22:30:00

[image]

Comment: What is the data type? Also: it is silly to use different versions in development and production. And 9.2 has been dead so long it smells bad.

Comment: timetz time with zone is datatype i used in both

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe but in linux this version is not released

Comment: [Don't use timetz](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_timetz)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but how can i store utc time in proper way?

Comment: A `time` itself does not really have a time zone to begin with. This only makes sense in combination with a date, so you should use  `timestamptz` instead. Otherwise just store the "UTC time" (whatever that means) in a `time` column (without `tz`)

Comment: If you visit the PostgreSQL page, you'll find Linux binaries for all versions and all distributions.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe okay sure

Answer (score 0):

I got one solution to solve this issue, so I add gmt offset with actual time so my insert query like below,

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (start_time) VALUES ('18:00:00+05:30');
```

now i got correct time

> > 17:00:00

before that i used direct time (18:00:00) string to insert record so problem was occurred in time conversion (version 12.3 08:00:00+05:30 and postgres 9.2 stored 23:00:00 )